# Как сделать чтоб элемент tabpage находился справа

Tags: c#, winforms

Cоздал tabcontrol элемент и добавил 2 элемента tabpage, они добавились друг за другом слева направо, а теперь хочу добавить снова элемент tabpage но хочу чтобы располагался с краю справа. Как сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `TabPage` не может располагаться справа. Он заполняет собой весь `TabControl`. Вы имеете в виду его ярлык?

Comment: Скриншот в студию! Как есть сейчас и как планируете сделать, подрисовать можно в паинте.

Comment: @Neolisk Добавил скрин

Comment: @SVD102, так можно в WPF сделать, но в WinForms так не сделать, вроде.

Answer (score 1):

WinForms не позволяет отображать часть табов с одной стороны, а часть табов -- с другой стороны. Либо все табы слева, либо все табы справа.